# Using regex to manipulate string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I currently have a regex method that removes a specific series of characters from an existing text file, although how could I do this with a string instead?

e.g. remove any occurrences of "xyz" from s string

The code I have so far:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"Command.bat"), @"test", string.Empty);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Command.bat", result);
```

Comment: @James, are you trying to do this with a string variable?

Comment: I don't see any `s` string with occurrences of `"xyz"`. If I wanted my question to be properly answered, I would keep my question and code sample synchronized.

Comment: You should favor the `Replace` method of the `string` class over regular expressions to do simple replacements. `Replace` is easier, faster, and better to read.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh.. it already does it with a string.  ReadAllText returns a string, and WriteAllText writes a string... so all you have to do is change the `File.ReadAllText` to a string and you're done.

In other words:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(@"test string", @"test", string.Empty);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Command.bat", result);
```

EDIT:

Your code above can be rewritten as:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(@"Command.bat");
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"test", string.Empty);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Command.bat", result);
```

So as you can see, Regex.Replace already accepts a string, does this make it any more clear?

Comment: shouldnt it be: var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"test", string.Empty); ?

Comment: No dice, this answer is not correct, so no best answer for you.

Comment: @James - The answer is entirely correct.  YOu wanted to do the above code but with a string, and that is what it does.  Unless you have different requirements that you expect us to derive psychically, this answers the questions you asked.  And if you want to use a string variable, then you can replace @"test string" with whatever you want, you didn't specify an external string in your question.  @"test string" is just as much as string as `string s`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use string you can use the `Replace` function of the string.

```
var line = "bansskgngxyz".Replace("xyz","");
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, where is the "s" string?

Comment: "bansskgngxyz" would be the string s. string s = "bansskgngxyz";

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "xyz";
var newS = Regex.Replace(s, "test", "");
```